# Formatting Appendix Labels and its TOC Entry in the Report Document Class

Tags: sectioning, appendices, report

I'm using the standard TOC and appendix functionality in a `report` document class, in PDFLatex. Relevantly, I have

```
\documentclass{report}

....

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    ...

    \chapter{Appendix}
    \appendix

        \section{Testing the LaTeX Appendix}
        \label{app:test1}
            hello

        \section{Testing Referencing to the Appendix}
        \label{app:test2}
            goodbye

\end{document}
```

This creates a TOC which looks like

> [image: a snippet of the TOC when using appendix sections]

and an appendix section like

> [image: a snippet of the appendix chapter when using appendix sections]

The issue is that the appendix section labels don't have a leading chapter number (e.g. they are **.1** instead of **8.1**, or better yet, **8.A**), but I do like that the appendix sections appear as subsections of Appendix in the TOC.

Clearly this is because I define the appendix sections with `\section` whilst I'm using the `report` environment. However, changing my appendix sections to chapters like so...

```
\chapter{Appendix}
\appendix

    \chapter{Testing the LaTeX Appendix}
    \label{app:test1}
        hello

    \chapter{Testing Referencing to the Appendix}
    \label{app:test2}
        goodbye
```

makes each of them be treated like independent chapters (save a label change), which muddles up both the TOC...

> [image: a snippet of the TOC when using appendix chapters]

and the actual appendix sections...

> [image: a snippet of the appendix chapter when using appendix chapters]

How can I format my TOC and appendix entries like in the former case, though with the correct label numbers? The best outcome would see the appendix labels formatted as **8.A**, etc.

Note I have attempted use of the appendix package and the `begin{indices}` environments with the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redefine the `\appendix` switch in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
 \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
 \gdef\thesection{\thechapter.\@Alph\c@section}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{7}

    \appendix
    \chapter{Appendix}

        \section{Testing the LaTeX Appendix}
        \label{app:test1}
            hello

        \section{Testing Referencing to the Appendix}
        \label{app:test2}
            goodbye

\end{document}
```

[image]